# D3 selection no longer updates after supplying new data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Creating a new selection, and supplying the data works:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");

var _nodeSelection = svg.insert("g").selectAll(".node");
var _nodeData = _nodeSelection.data(_nodes);

_nodeData
.enter().append("text")
.attr("class", "node");
```

After some callback the attributes to all the existing elements change, This works!

```js
_nodeData.attr("class", "update");
```

In another callback I supply new data to the selection, and try to update the existing selection before calling the Enter / Exit routine.

```js
// No longer works after supplying new data
var _nodeData = _nodeSelection.data(_nodes);

// Does not work anymore:
_nodeData.attr("class", "update2");
```

This no longer works, as in the class does NOT get updated to update2. This is surprising to me as according to this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808221) this should work.

Consequently, calling .Enter() on the new data selection creates a new set of elements in the sample place as the old elements, so that all the svg elements are duplicated.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hard to tell without a complete example. Most likely the DOM is changing underneath but you're not updating your selections. Try selecting explicitly when you want to change, i.e. instead of `_nodeSelection` use `svg.selectAll(".node")`.

Answer (score 1):

You always have to reselect explicitly using `selectall`. D3 does an explicit internal binding on a selection when supplying the data, and this cannot be applied on the same selection twice.